# ScrollView not working with Drawables Android

Tags: android, orientation, scrollview, drawable, tablelayout

I am using `Html.fromHtml()` to get content and display it on my activity. To do this I am using an ImageGetter. I was having a problem that if the phone could not connect to the internet the app crashed as the pictures could not load. Instead I wanted to have a placeholder image saved in my `ldpi/mdpi/...etc` folders that would be inserted whenever a picture could not be loaded.

My ImageGetter uses URLImageParser which has the following onPostExecute() method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        //check to see if an image was found (if not could
        //be due to no internet)
        if(result ==null){
            //the drawable wasn't found so use the image not found
            //png
            Drawable imageNotFound = a.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_not_found);
            result = imageNotFound;
        }

        intrinsicHeight = result.getIntrinsicHeight();
        intrinsicWidth = result.getIntrinsicWidth();

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width = dm.widthPixels -50;
        int height = width * intrinsicHeight / intrinsicWidth;

        result.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + width, 0 
                + height);

        urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0+width, 0+height);  

        // change the reference of the current drawable to the result 
        // from the HTTP call 
        urlDrawable.drawable = result; 

        // redraw the image by invalidating the container 
        URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();

        // For ICS
        URLImageParser.this.container.setHeight((URLImageParser.this.container.getHeight() 
        + height));

        // Pre ICS
        URLImageParser.this.container.setEllipsize(null);
    }
```

I have simply inserted the if`(result==null)` statement at the top of this method. But now if the pictures can be loaded the app works perfectly. If the images cannot be loaded and the placeholders are used instead I get some odd behavior.

The scrollview never scrolls to the bottom of the screen, and I have no idea why this is. In theory there should be no difference between my imageNotFound drawable (which is a png file) and the files downloaded off the internet. The scrollview will only move slightly.

I have no idea what is causing this. When searching online most people seem to be having problems with RelativeLayouts. I couldn't find anyone having trouble with drawables or TableLayouts.

My xml for the layout is as follows:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:paddingBottom = "0dip"
  android:orientation = "vertical" >


<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1"
    android:shrinkColumns="0,1"
    android:id = "@+id/SharedTableLayout"
    android:paddingBottom = "0dip" >

    <TableRow
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:paddingBottom = "0dip">
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id = "@+id/SharedTableContent"
             android:layout_span="2"
             android:gravity = "left"
             android:paddingLeft = "10dip"
             android:paddingRight = "10dip"
             android:paddingTop = "20dip"
             android:paddingBottom = "0dip"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions on this, I've been stuck on it for weeks.

Thanks for your time

The TextView with id SharedTableContent displays a string that was converted from html using Html.fromHtml() so the images may be surrounded by text which means I cannot hard code a solution into xml as there is no way of telling how many images there will be to download in advance, thats all done programmatically.

Comment: Instead of `ScrollView` why don't u try with [`List View`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) any specific reason and for loading image use [`volley`](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) or [`picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: I'm relatively new to android, I've never heard of ListView. Would it automatically scroll?

Comment: yes of course it will scroll `vertically`

Comment: At the moment the content I am putting in the Textview with id SharedTableContent isn't just images, it's text and it may or may not have images in between chunks of text. So I'm using Html.fromHtml to display it. In order to get a list view to work would I need to split the content so that each list item is either a chunk of text or an image? thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think a ListView would work as I need to display both images and text and I don't want each element to be scrollable in it's own right

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the layout width of the scrollview to match_parent.

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

Or try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView02" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView01" 
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
           android:src="@drawable/pic" 
           android:isScrollContainer="true" 
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:adjustViewBounds="true">
</ImageView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Weirdly, that makes it scroll a little farther than usual, until I rotate the phone. Then it barely rotates at all as before.

I also have since added android:fillViewport="true" which didn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: `ScrollView` inside another `ScrollView` is a very bad *idea*

Comment: I don't think I can code things in xml like this. The textview with id SharedTableContent is used to display a String from html which may or may not contain images. And the images can be in between chunks of text. Thanks for your suggestions by the way